# Items vs item loaders in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm pretty new to scrapy, I know that items are used to populate scraped data, but I cant understand the difference between items and item loaders. I tried to read some example codes, they used item loaders to store instead of items and I can't understand why. Scrapy documentation wasn't clear enough for me. Can anyone give a simple explanation (better with example) about when item loaders are used and what additional facilities do they provide over items ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I really like the official explanation in the docs:

> Item Loaders provide a convenient mechanism for populating scraped
>   Items. Even though Items can be populated using their own
>   dictionary-like API, Item Loaders provide a much more convenient API
>   for populating them from a scraping process, by automating some common
>   tasks like parsing the raw extracted data before assigning it.
>
> **In other words, Items provide the container of scraped data, while
>   Item Loaders provide the mechanism for populating that container.**

Last paragraph should answer your question.
Item loaders are great since they allow you to have so many processing shortcuts and reuse a bunch of code to keep everything tidy, clean and understandable.

Comparison example case. Lets say we want to scrape this item:

```
class MyItem(Item):
    full_name = Field()
    bio = Field()
    age = Field()
    weight = Field()
    height = Field()
```

Item only approach would look something like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    full_name = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'name')]/text()").extract()
    # i.e. returns ugly ['John\n', '\n\t  ', '  Snow']
    item['full_name'] = ' '.join(i.strip() for i in full_name if i.strip())
    bio = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'bio')]/text()").extract()
    item['bio'] = ' '.join(i.strip() for i in full_name if i.strip())
    age = response.xpath("//div[@class='age']/text()").extract_first(0)
    item['age'] = int(age) 
    weight = response.xpath("//div[@class='weight']/text()").extract_first(0)
    item['weight'] = int(age) 
    height = response.xpath("//div[@class='height']/text()").extract_first(0)
    item['height'] = int(age) 
    return item
```

vs Item Loaders approach:

```
# define once in items.py 
from scrapy.loader.processors import Compose, MapCompose, Join, TakeFirst
clean_text = Compose(MapCompose(lambda v: v.strip()), Join())   
to_int = Compose(TakeFirst(), int)

class MyItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_item_class = MyItem
    full_name_out = clean_text
    bio_out = clean_text
    age_out = to_int
    weight_out = to_int
    height_out = to_int

# parse as many different places and times as you want  
def parse(self, response):
    loader = MyItemLoader(selector=response)
    loader.add_xpath('full_name', "//div[contains(@class,'name')]/text()")
    loader.add_xpath('bio', "//div[contains(@class,'bio')]/text()")
    loader.add_xpath('age', "//div[@class='age']/text()")
    loader.add_xpath('weight', "//div[@class='weight']/text()")
    loader.add_xpath('height', "//div[@class='height']/text()")
    return loader.load_item()
```

As you can see the Item Loader is so much cleaner and easier to scale. Let's say you have 20 more fields from which a lot share the same processing logic, would be a suicide to do it without Item Loaders.
Item Loaders are awesome and you should use them!

Comment: The item example creates a lot of unnecessary variables which makes it look a lot more cluttered, `item["bio"] = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'bio')]/text()").extract()`

Comment: Cool stuff. Thank you !

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I don't see any unnecessary variables here since `bio` field has to be striped and joined. Your example would just put a list of values with no clean up.

Comment: I might be wrong but I feel that `ItemLoader`s added value lies in using small and shared (repetitive) functions among many projects, other than that I don't see why to use them

Comment: Thanks for this! Can I just confirm if you put the class `MyItemLoader` and the function `parse` in items.py? I thought that `parse` would go in the spider?

Comment: @Maverick parse goes in your spider. I was just saving space.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, been trying to get this straight in my mind ad was a little thrown off by the thought they might be both stored in items. One more thing I'm trying to understand, why does `default_item_class` equal `MyItem`?

Comment: @Maverick Itemloader needs a class for items it generates, `default_item_class`  class variable specifies default class that will be used, otherwise you'd need to supply `item` arguemnt everytime you initiate your loader.

Comment: @Granitosaurus Can you please elaborate, "parse as many different places and times as you want " ?